# The Eucledian norm of the gradient of a convex function

Tags: calculus, general-topology, convex-analysis

Here is the problem I've been wondering about the past few days:

Let $g(x):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function which is differentiable everywhere on its domain.

Is the set

$S := \{~ x ~ | ~ ||\nabla_x g(x)||_2 \leq c \}$

convex for some positive constant $c$?

Comment: No, consider $g(x,y) = x^2/\sqrt{x^2+1} + y^2/\sqrt{y^2+1}$.

Comment: I was just visualizing the set for $|| \nabla g(x,y) ||_2 \leq 0.5,1,100$ and they look all convex to me.. am I missing something?

Comment: The set $\|\nabla g\|\le c=100$ is $\mathbb R^2$ so of course it's convex :) Have you tried $c=1.1$? But sorry, my $g$ is not convex in the first place! A minor correction fixes it: $g(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}$. (I'm choosing a smooth function similar to the $L^1$ norm.) Then $\|\nabla g\|\le 1$ iff $x^2y^2\le1$.

Comment: Thanks! That counter example is perfect! Put it as an answer if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any smooth approximation of the $1$-norm will do: its gradient will have magnitude approximately $\sqrt{\|x\|_0}$, which is not a quasiconvex function. For example, take
$$g(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{y^2+1}.$$
The norm of its gradient is
$$\|\nabla g(x,y)\| = \left\|\begin{bmatrix}\cfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \\ \cfrac y{\sqrt{y^2+1}} \end{bmatrix}\right\| = \frac{x^2}{x^2+1} + \frac{y^2}{y^2+1},$$
and $\|\nabla g(x,y)\|\le 1$ if and only if $x^2y^2\le 1$.